# Doing 2 tasks synchronously in renderer: update at time

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to fade out a node while fading in a different node simultaneously  inside `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {`.

I was wondering if doing one of the SCNActions on the background thread would work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCNAction` is a nice utility class provided by SceneKit to modify an attribute by a small increment each time the scene is rendered giving a nice animation.

The `updateAtTime` function is called only once each time the scene is rendered. In this function you can modify your scene and these modifications will show immediately. You can obtain the same animation effect as `SCNAction` by only making small incremental changes to the scene.

eg; in your `updateAtTime` function try putting something like the following in. This should fade out your `myNodeA` node, and fade in the `myNodeB` (assuming scene setup sets opacity to 0) over a total of 100 frames.

```
self.myNodeA.opacity -= 0.01
self.myNodeB.opacity += 0.01
```

Would recommend against running a `SCNAction` from a background thread, especially from within the `updateAtTime` function. Both are quite valid approaches to achieving what you want, just use one or the other (not both).

[Documentation is worth a read](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate)